# "unable to read repository" when configuring Wildfly as target environment in Eclipse 2023-12

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

When configuring my project's targeted runtime (I try to add Wildfly) via Project/Properties/Targeted Runtime/New), expand 'Red Hat JBoss Middleware' and choose 'JBoss AS, Wildfly,  & EAP Server Tools' I get this message:

```
Unable to read repository at 
https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/webtools/photon/content.xml.
```

Indeed when I try this URL from curl I get a certificate error. Ignoring that I get HTTP status 404. Looking up https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/webtools/photon/ I can see that indeed the file `content.xml` does not exist. So either Eclipse may not like the certificate or is using the wrong URL.

How can I find out the exact problem, and even more: what can I do to fix it?

On my PC I freshly installed

- Windows Version 10.0.19045.3930
- Microsoft Java C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot
- Eclipse 2023-12 (Java EE edition)
- Wilfly 29.0.1.Final

Eclipse is running on the bundled JVM C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-2023-12-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.9.v20231028-0858

My company has an intercepting proxy.

Comment: `https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/webtools/photon/` works for me as an p2 update site. You will get this error only when none of the files `compositeContent.jar`, `compositeContent.xml`, `content.jar` and `content.xml` cannot be read, but  [`compositeContent.xml`](https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/webtools/photon/compositeContent.xml) exists. Are you behind a proxy? Use the [_Repository Explorer_ view](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Oomph_Repository_Explorer) which is part of [_Oomph Targlets_](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Oomph_Targlets) to explore p2 repositories.

Comment: 404 is for `content.xml` which does indeed not exist. What do you get for https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/webtools/photon/compositeContent.xml ? I can confirm that the JVM you use contains the right certifications to access the mentioned HTTPS update site. So there is nothing to fix here.

Comment: Well, since the intercepting proxy uses it's own certificate chain the JVM did not have the right certifications to access the update site I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting more information about the issue is crucial, and this should have been the first hint actually:

Find the logfile in `<Eclipse's workspace>/.metadata/.log`
In there errors like this one became visible:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2024-01-24 10:36:36.061
!MESSAGE Connection to https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/webtools/photon/site.xml failed on PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Retry attempt 0 started
!STACK 0
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

With that it is evident that the intercepting proxy is an issue. I used my default webbrowser and accessed the problematic url, then exported the root certificate used into a .pem file. Next, I used [Portecle](https://portecle.sourceforge.net/) to import that into the Eclipse's VM's truststore at `C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-2023-12-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.9.v20231028-0858\jre\lib\security\cacerts`. After restarting Eclipse it would happily download all the addons - even updates.

Disadvantage: A new VM was downloaded, so I will have to patch that VM's truststore again...